# From Riemann Sum to Definite Integral

Tags: definite-integrals, riemann-sum

I have the sum
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^T\frac{1}{h}g\left(\frac{\omega_j-\omega}{h}\right)f(\omega_j),\quad \omega_j = \frac{2\pi j}{T}
\end{align*}
where $h>0$ and $\omega \in[0,\pi]$. I'm asked to find the integral it approximates. Any clues on how to proceed?

Comment: Writing out some of the sum's terms may help:$$\frac1h \left[g\left(\frac{\frac{2\pi}{T}-\omega}{h}\right)f\left(\frac{2\pi}{T}\right) + g\left(\frac{\frac{4\pi}{T}-\omega}{h}\right)f\left(\frac{4\pi}{T}\right) + \cdots + g\left(\frac{2\pi-\omega}{h}\right)f\left(2\pi\right)\right]$$The pattern in the argument to $f$ suggests an integral taken over $[0,2\pi]$, while the corresponding argument to $g$ suggests the overall integral is a convolution.

Comment: Something like 
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{h}\int_{0}^{2\pi}g\left(\frac{\theta - \omega}{h}\right)f(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta,
\end{align*}
right?

Comment: *Something* like that, yes, but I don't think that's exactly it. There still seem to be some missing pieces to the sum.

Comment: Sure, I guess the two are equivalent as $T\to\infty$. I also know that $g(\cdot)$ and $f(\cdot)$ are non-negative functions, thus I should be able to claim that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^T\frac{1}{h}g\left(\frac{\omega_j-\omega}{h}\right)f(\omega_j)\leq \frac{1}{h}\int_0^{2\pi}g\left(\frac{\theta-\omega}{h}\right)f(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta
\end{align*}